# Javascript search with parser

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get this code working with my parser.

```
function search() {
var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
input = document.getElementById("input");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

parser:

```
function load() {
data = data[0];
var uno = document.getElementById('data');
for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++)
{
    var content = uno.innerHTML;
    content += "<div class='grid-item'><div class='inside' id='item" + i + "'><h2 id='contents" + i + "' class='pl-content-title' href=./index.html#" + data.list[i].hash + ">" + data.list[i].title + "</h2><div class='collapsing'><br><table id='mytable'>";
    for(var e = 0; e < data.list[i].content.length; e++)
    {
        content += "<tr><td class='tabledata'><a class='pl-content' href=./index.html#" + data.list[i].content[e].hash + ">" + data.list[i].content[e].title + "</a></td></tr>";
    }
    uno.innerHTML = content + "</table></div></div></div>";
}
```

html:

```
<input class="pl-search" type="text" placeholder="Suche" id="input" onkeyup="search()">
```

If I copy the table directly into my html it works but it doesnt if the table is built by my parser script. 
The error message from the browser console is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: What is your parser script? Do you have a table with id `myTable`? How are we supposed to help you if you don't show the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: sry I thought this was irrelevant. Ill post my parser script

Comment: It's just because you mention it. I'm not really sure it's relevant either. If not, why did you mention it and why is it important in the context of the question? I'd say the table is more important, actually, since the problem seems to be that `document.getElementById("myTable")` returns `null`.

Comment: but it works if the same table is built in the html. the parser is in the post now.

Comment: Seeing your code, you're giving the table and `id` of `mytable`, while the script is trying to get `myTable`. `id`s are case-sensitive.

Comment: this makes me want to die... however ty lol

Comment: is it possible to make my search function work with many more tables and the same inputfield?

Comment: give them a class name and then query by class name, and use a forloop like you did the table rows;

Comment: yep, use a class instead of an id (and amend the script to cycle through the results of `document.getElementsByClassName`). But that's a completely different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table id='mytable'>
```

should be

```
<table id='myTable'>
```

This typo caused `table = document.getElementById("myTable");` to return null.

In a static example like this, you just fix the typo.

When coding a dynamic function, prevent errors by using a fallback

```
tr = table ? table.getElementsByTagName("tr") : null;
```

and so on with `tr` when you evaluate the `for`. (declare k)

```
for (i = 0, k= tr ? tr.length : 0; i < k; i++)
```

Comment: Or, you know, just fix the typo.

Comment: This is not more robust, this will just crash further down the line when you'll try to get `tr.length` and generally just stop working.

Comment: using too much fallbacks is not good because it can make the code hard to debug. Let it throw that error so that you know that the name is incorrect on first sight. (that is why you need to test your own code first). That is more OK when working with dynamic names.

Comment: I already mentioned but just edited it anyway according to suggestions.